# java reset StyleSheet rules

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am working on a school project where I have to make a HTML editor + viewer in java. So i have the main window with a button which opens a new window with a preview. The problem is thats every time you open the preview it does not reset the rules! So if you gave a background to the page, and then you Removed that CSS it will still hav background color.

This is the code for the preview:

```
public Preview(String html, String css) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 783, 629);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
        editorPane.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(editorPane);

        HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        editorPane.setEditorKit(kit);

        StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
        styleSheet.addRule(css);

        Document doc = kit.createDefaultDocument();
        editorPane.setDocument(doc);
        editorPane.setText(html);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I checked and saw thats after I added the rules it keeps them, even if i create a new HTMLEditorKit, Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: As an aside: *"working on a school project where I have to make a HTML editor"*  My condolences.  I don't really see the benefit of a learning exercise dealing with Swing's (very quirky & incomplete) HTML/CSS implementation.

Comment: This is the easiest way i found to do it, I know there is a better way to it, but i can't find any good library which does it, If you know about a library for viewing html and css, I would be more than happy to use it.

Comment: There is also the `WebView` of Java-FX, but I'm not sure it offers a DOM of the web page, as Swing does.

Comment: ok, thanks, i will check and see